# Ignore hard link addition and removal when tarring a bunch of files

Tags: unix, cassandra, tar

I'm executing the following command:

```
find /var/lib/cassandra -name $snapshotName | tar -cvf $snapshotTarballPath -T -
```

and this is failing with the following error:

```
tar: /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/compaction_history-b4dbb7b4dc493fb5b3bfce6e434832ca/snapshots/c85af1c2-1636-4662-be34-91caee3d66a3_1476398902806/mc-14-big-Statistics.db: file changed as we read it
```

Based on the following link, it seems this is likely due to changes in the set of hard links referring to the file that changed, since the actual content of the db files should not be changing inside snapshot directories in cassandra: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nosql-databases/2vBHDhGti9E

What is the best workaround for this to ignore such changes to hard links for files being copied, but not ignore the actual content of the file changing?

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution or work around to this problem?